# sqlite3 autoincrement - am I missing something?

Tags: sqlite, sequence

I want to create unique order numbers for each day. So ideally, in PostgreSQL for instance, I could create a sequence and read it back for these unique numbers, because the readback both gets me the new number and is atomic. Then at close of day, I'd reset the sequence.

In sqlite3, however, I only see an autoincrement for the integer field type. So say I set up a table with an autoincrement field, and insert a record to get the new number (seems like an awfully inefficient way to do it, but anyway...) When I go to read the max back, who is to say that another task hasn't gone in there and inserted ANOTHER record, thereby causing me to read back a miss, with my number one too far advanced (and a duplicate of what the other task reads back.)

Conceptually, I require:

- fast lock with wait for other tasks
- increment number
- retrieve number
- unlock

...I just don't see how to do that with sqlite3. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, autoincrementing fields are intended to be used as actual primary keys for their records.
You should just it as the ID for your orders table.

If you really want to have an atomic counter independent of corresponding table records, use a table with a single record.
ACID is ensured with transactions:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT number FROM MyTable;
UPDATE MyTable SET number = ? + 1;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, or else I don't understand it: Suppose I do this, then fetch the result, but before I get the result, some other process does it again? How do I get the result of MY counter increment before letting any other process increment again, thus feeding me the results of multiple increments? Remember, this isn't a counter, it's an orderID; I have to get a unique number, and I have to know what it is when I get it.

Comment: to elaborate: 1) I increment 2) other process increments 3) I read and get the double increment, 4) other process reads and gets same double increment. See the problem?

Comment: Transactions are [atomic](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html); you do not get conflicts when all dependent statements are inside one transaction.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. Atomicity guarantees that the STUFF1....n in the begin;STUFF1...STUFFn;commit; either all happens, or nothing happens. It does not prevent another process from doing the same thing in a different time scale. Proc one can select... get interrupted... proc 2 can select and gets the same value... proc 2 isn't interrupted... proc 2 writes in back with the commit... proc 1 resumes... does its commit... and now we've two cases with the same increment value being used. What you're thinking of is record locking. That's not the same as commit level atomicity.

Comment: SQLite guarantees full ACID; transactions are isolated.

Answer (score 0):

ok, looks like sqlite either doesn't have what I need, or I am missing it. Here's what I came up with:

- declare zorder as integer primary key autoincrement, zuid integer in orders table

  this means every new row gets an ascending number, starting with 1
- generate a random number:

  rnd = int(random.random() * 1000000) # unseeded python uses system time
- create new order (just the SQL for simplicity):

  'INSERT INTO orders (zuid) VALUES ('+str(rnd)+')'
- find that exact order number using the random number:

  'SELECT zorder FROM orders WHERE zuid = '+str(rnd)
- pack away that number as the new order number (newordernum)
- clobber the random number to reduce collision risks

  'UPDATE orders SET zuid = 0 WHERE zorder = '+str(newordernum)

...and now I have a unique new order, I know what the correct order number is, the risk of a read collision is reduced to negligible, and I can prepare that order without concern that I'm trampling on another newly created order.

Just goes to show you why DB authors implement sequences, lol.

Comment: This does not guarantee uniqueness; the probability of conflicts is quite high (see the birthday paradox), and two Python scripts running at the same time *with the same system time value* will increase the probability further.